# Mobile friendly website - Applying good resolution

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

Website is very nice converted for iphone: 1-4 and rest of mobile phones with the same resolution but if I add to metatags code for Iphone 5, previous code doesnt work and for all phones work iphone5 code.

My code:

```
    <link media="only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait)" href="wp-content/themes/chomacki/css/iphone4-portrait.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet" />    
    <link media="only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape)" href="wp-content/themes/chomacki/css/iphone4-landscape.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet" />  

    <link media="only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) and (orientation : portrait)" href="wp-content/themes/chomacki/css/iphone5-portrait.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet" />    
    <link media="only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) and (orientation : landscape)" href="wp-content/themes/chomacki/css/iphone5-landscape.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

How i can make both codes work? Not just iphone5 code, or Iphone4 code by deleting iphone5 code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link media="only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait)" href="wp-content/themes/chomacki/css/iphone4-portrait.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<link media="only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape)" href="wp-content/themes/chomacki/css/iphone4-landscape.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet" />  

<link media="only screen and (min-device-width : 481px) and (max-device-width : 568px) and (orientation : portrait)" href="wp-content/themes/chomacki/css/iphone5-portrait.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<link media="only screen and (min-device-width : 481px) and (max-device-width : 568px) and (orientation : landscape)" href="wp-content/themes/chomacki/css/iphone5-landscape.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Is probably what you want. It is not a good idea to have overlapping Media CSS queries.

Comment: "It is not a good idea to have overlapping Media CSS queries" <- says who?

Comment: @cimmanon Well this question probably shows that it doesn't work :)

Comment: It is probably because the iPhone5 example is last in the overlapping codes, so because the full css is in each one, it overrides the iPhone 1-4 one. @Lethysek Try swapping the two segments (iPhone 4&5) around and see if the problem swaps too.

Comment: This question is a good example of *why you shouldn't do it that way* in the first place.

Comment: agreed! If it is for iPhones, use javascript User Agents:)